# access value from custom directive of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new to angularjs and I am trying to learn it. Kindly sorry me if I ask some dumb ass question as I am on learning curve.

I have created reusable custom  directive which is working very good. My full code is at 
http://plnkr.co/edit/GxM78QRwSjTrsX1SCxF7?p=preview

```
$scope.validateSingle = function(item) {
                    $scope.text = item[$scope.textField] + ($scope.textField2 !== '' ? " (" + item[$scope.textField2] + ")" : "");
                    $scope.value = item[$scope.valueField];
                    console.log($scope.value);
                    $scope.placeholder = 'placeholderBlack';
                    $scope.hideItems();
                    if (typeof $scope.callback == 'function') {
                        $scope.callback($scope.value);
                    }
                }
```

I am also assigning that value in the above code which is part of my plunker

Now my issue is after I select item I want to get it value for later use, which I did assign in $scope.validateSingle function with $scope.value but I don't know how to access it and If I have more than 1 directive on the page than how can we access its value independently

I want directive working like drop-down once I selected item and if I wanted its value in some button click then i could use like dropdown.value where dropdown could be id of the directive. Hope I could clear my point.

Comment: I already added my plunker but on your comment I also added codes

Comment: Links including Punkr should be used as a reference only as there is no guarantees that the links will still be alive in the future.

Comment: ANd please don't use URL shorteners , easy to mask spam that way. You want us to click the link, let us know what it is

Comment: Do you want to pass it to a controller, or where do you want to store it?

Comment: I want directive working like drop-down once I selected item and if I wanted its value in some button click  then i could use like dropdown.value where dropdown could be id of the directive.

Hope I could clear my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you I am learning curve and I tried to put the same question in different forums but I could not got the answer

But suddenly something trigger in my mind that why we can't use **ngModal** which act as ngBind which I want, so first in my directive I added

```
require: 'ngModel',
```

Then in my $scope.validateSingle function I added `ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.value);` where $scope.value I was assigning with selected value so my validateSingle function become like this

```
            $scope.validateSingle = function(item) {
                $scope.text = item[$scope.textField] + ($scope.textField2 !== '' ? " (" + item[$scope.textField2] + ")" : "");
                $scope.value = item[$scope.valueField];
                $scope.placeholder = 'placeholderBlack';
                $scope.hideItems();
                if (typeof $scope.callback == 'function') {
                    $scope.callback($scope.value);
                }

                ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.value);
            }
```

So bingo every thing working like charm as I was wanted. I edited my plunker also you can check on http://plnkr.co/edit/GxM78QRwSjTrsX1SCxF7?p=preview

Hope it will help to some new learner